# Problem with library libpq in Debian

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc, debian, libpq

I'm installing postgresql 8.4 in Debian, put program testlibpq.c from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/libpq-example.html to directory which have file libpq-fe.h, but after compilation gcc write me

```
testlibpq.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `PQconnectdb'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `PQstatus'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `PQexec'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `PQresultStatus'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `PQerrorMessage'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0xf5): undefined reference to `PQclear'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `PQclear'
testlibpq.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `PQexec'
```

... e.t.c. What I must suppose to do to correct work?

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're not linking the PostgreSQL library. You should be compiling `testlibpq.c` with something like this:

```
gcc -o testlibpq testlibpq.c -lpq
```

The `-lpq` tells the linker to link against the PostgreSQL library and that's where `PQconnectdb` and friends come from.

You may need to tell the compiler where to find the libraries and headers as well, if so then something like this should sort that out:

```
gcc -o testlibpq -I$(pg_config --includedir) -L$(pg_config --libdir) -o testlibpq $(pg_config --libs)
```